# I am trying to prove Euler's equation for the case of $4x$, that is: $e^{i4x} = \cos 4x+i \sin 4x.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove Euler's equation for the case of $4x$, that is:
$$e^{i4x} = \cos 4x+i \sin 4x.$$
I can get the imaginary part in a form that is equivalent to $\sin 4x$, but I am struggling with the real part, for which I keep getting $$\cos^4(x)-6 \cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)+\sin^4(x),$$
which I cannot equate to $\cos 4x$. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show your work for the imaginary part? Can you show your work for the real part, where did u get stuck?

Comment: It looks correct to me?

Comment: What is your starting point ? Is it $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, in which case there is not much to show, just set $x=4y$ and you are done. It seems you are trying instead to express $\cos(4x),\sin(4x)$ in function of $\cos(x)^n,\sin(x)^n$ factors ?

Comment: You could also induct, as in the proof of De Moivre’s formula

Comment: $e^{ix} = C + iS  \implies e^{inx} = C_{nx} + iS_{nx}$
$$e^{i4x} =C_{4x} + iS_{4x}= C^4 + 4C^3(iS) + 6C^2(iS)^2 + 4C(iS)^3 + (iS)^4$$
To compare the real parts lets only take the even powers of $(iS)$ for $\cos 4x $ 
$$\implies \cos 4x = C^4 - 6C^2S^2 + S^4$$
The above method gives you $\cos 4x $ in terms of powers of $\cos$ and $\sin $ $\cos nx = f(\cos x, \sin x)$  so, 
[So, I have added answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363566/i-am-trying-to-prove-eulers-equation-for-the-case-of-4x-that-is-ei4x/4363585#4363585) where $\cos {nx}$ in terms of $g(\cos mx )$; f: poly g: Lin

Comment: $e^{i2x}=(\cos x + i \sin x)^2=\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x + 2i \sin x \cos x = \cos 2x+ i \sin 2x\,$, then write the same equality again for $\,x \mapsto 2x\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\cos(2x)= \cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$ twice:

$$\cos(4x) \\= (\cos(2x))^2-(\sin(2x))^2 \\= (\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))^2-(2\cos(x)\sin(x))^2 \\= \cos^4(x) - 2\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)+\sin^4(x) - 4\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x) \\= \cos^4(x) - 6\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)+\sin^4(x) $$

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It's been years since I was in school last, and my trig is still frustratingly rusty. Thank, you, Henry!

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are looking for?

\begin{align*}
\cos(4x) & = 2\cos^{2}(2x) - 1\\\\
& = 2(2\cos^{2}(x) - 1)^{2} - 1\\\\
& = 2(4\cos^{4}(x) - 4\cos^{2}(x) + 1) - 1\\\\
& = 8\cos^{4}(x) - 8\cos^{2}(x) + 1
\end{align*}

If you prefer to make progress based on your attempt, here it is:
\begin{align*}
\cos^{4}(x) - 6\sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{4}(x) & = \cos^{4}(x) - 6(1 - \cos^{2}(x))\cos^{2}(x) + (1 - \cos^{2}(x))^{2}\\\\
& = 7\cos^{4}(x) - 6\cos^{2}(x) + (1 - 2\cos^{2}(x) + \cos^{4}(x))\\\\
& = 8\cos^{4}(x) - 8\cos^{2}(x) + 1
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\frac {e^{ix} + e^{-x}}{2}\right) =\left(\frac {u+ \frac 1u}{2}\right)= \cos x$$
$4$rth power:

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac {u + \frac 1u}{2}\right)^4
&= \cos^4 x = \frac {u^4 + 4u^3\frac 1u + 6u^2\frac 1{u^2} + 4u\frac 1{u3} + \frac 1{u^4}}{2^4} \\
&= \frac {\left(\left(u^4 + \frac 1{u^4}\right) + 4\left(u^2 + \frac 1{u^2}\right) + 6\right)}{2^4}\\
& = \frac {2\color{red}{\cos 4x} + 4\times 2 \times \cos 2x + 6}{2^4}
\end{align*}$$

You can separate for red part $\cos 4x$;

Comment: This helps a lot. Evidently I was doing everything right, but I did not recognize how I could derive cos4x from what  I had for the real part of the expression. Thank you and eveyone else!